# Facebook: why are results not returned with valid access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections), an array of posts for a page can be retrieved with any valid access token:

And indeed, using the Graph API Explorer it's possible to [demonstrate this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=redbull?fields=posts).  When I copy this access token to my app (using Koala) I get the same result.  So far so good.

But when I make the same request using my app access token I get an empty array.

It seems to depend on the page because for example [this one](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=nike?fields=posts) doesn't display the same behavior

Any idea why this might be?

(Also, the API also seems to show a behaviour where if you specify a historical time period using 'since' & 'until' it returns more results than if no time period is specified.  Can you shed any light on this? )

**Clarification**

The 'app access token' I am using is of the form MY_APP_ID|xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx and was generated by following the Facebook instructions on '[obtain app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/)'

Comment: Would you clarify "my app access token"? Can you check if the access token you're using is real one or the generic which if I remember correct was APP_ID|USER_ID or something similar

Comment: Most likely there is something more to be seen here in your code, because you *can* use an app access token to retrieve posts.

Comment: @phwd I also replicated this problem in the Graph API explorer so it's definitely not in the code.

Comment: I have tested all your pages with an app access token and it works and shows the correct json responses.

Comment: Thanks @phwd.  I just tested it in the API explorer with my app access token and still got the problem.  Good to know that this is meant to work.  I will get a totally new app access token and hopefully that will solve the problem.  Appreciate your help.